# Elasticsearch - filtering results by cardinality

Tags: json, elasticsearch, filter

Filter by cardinality

I'm running this nested aggregation to get all groups that a candidate is associated with -

```
"aggs" : { "remove_empty":{  "filter": { "not": { "term": {"candidate_id":"NA"}} }, "aggs": {  "distinct_ids":{ "terms":{ "field":"candidate_id"}, "aggs":{ "distinct_groups":{  "terms":{ "field":"candidate_group" }}}} }  } }
```

This returns the expected result -

```
"aggregations":{  
      "remove_empty":{  
         "doc_count":160322,
         "distinct_ids":{  
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
            "sum_other_doc_count":0,
            "buckets":[  
               {  
                  "key":"1401",
                  "distinct_groups":{  
                     "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
                     "sum_other_doc_count":0,
                     "buckets":[  
                        {  
                           "key":"group4",
                           "doc_count":619
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               },
               {  
                  "key":"1402",
                  "distinct_groups":{  
                     "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
                     "sum_other_doc_count":0,
                     "buckets":[  
                        {  
                           "key":"group1",
                           "doc_count":619
                        },
                        {  
                           "key":"group6",
                           "doc_count":619
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               },
               {  
                  "key":"1403",
                  "distinct_groups":{  
                     "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
                     "sum_other_doc_count":0,
                     "buckets":[  
                        {  
                           "key":"group3",
                           "doc_count":619
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               },
               {  
                  "key":"1404",
                  "distinct_groups":{  
                     "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
                     "sum_other_doc_count":0,
                     "buckets":[  
                        {  
                           "key":"group6",
                           "doc_count":619
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
```

However, I only need the candidate_ids that are associated with two or more groups like this -

```
{  
  "key":"1402",
  "distinct_groups":{  
     "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
     "sum_other_doc_count":0,
     "buckets":[  
        {  
           "key":"group1",
           "doc_count":619
        },
        {  
           "key":"group6",
           "doc_count":619
        }
     ]
  }
}
```

Is there a way to filter by cardinality > 1 in this query?